# `stream` does not live long enough

Tags: rust, static, stream, lifetime, borrow-checker

Could anyone please help me with this error?

```
error[E0597]: `stream` does not live long enough
   --> src\pty\ws_server.rs:91:21
    |
91  |     let ws_stream = stream.by_ref();
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                     |
    |                     borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                     argument requires that `stream` is borrowed for `'static`
...
131 | }
    | - `stream` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This is the function where I get the error

```rust
use bytes::BytesMut;
use futures::stream::{SplitSink, SplitStream};
use futures::{SinkExt, StreamExt};
use mt_logger::*;
use portable_pty::{native_pty_system, CommandBuilder, PtyPair, PtySize};
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message;
use tokio_tungstenite::{accept_async, WebSocketStream};

async fn accept_connection(stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut stream = accept_async(stream)
        .await
        .expect("Failed to accept");
    let ws_stream = stream.by_ref();
    let (ws_sender, ws_receiver) = ws_stream.split();   

    // ...

    let _child = pty_pair.slave.spawn_command(cmd).unwrap();

    let pty_reader = pty_pair.master.try_clone_reader().unwrap();
    let pty_writer = pty_pair.master.try_clone_writer().unwrap();

    std::thread::spawn(|| {
        let rt = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
        rt.block_on(async {
            feed_client_from_pty(pty_reader, ws_sender).await;
        })
    });

    feed_pty_from_ws(ws_receiver, pty_writer, pty_pair).await;
}


pub async fn pty_serve() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(PTY_SERVER_ADDRESS)
        .await
        .expect("Can't listen");

    while let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        let peer = stream
            .peer_addr()
            .expect("connected streams should have a peer address");
        mt_log!(Level::Info, "Peer address: {}", peer);

        std::thread::spawn(|| {
            let rt = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
            rt.block_on(async {
                accept_connection(stream).await;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I have to call `.by_ref()` because I need to use the `ws_stream` multiple times. If I don't use `.by_ref`, `.split()` will take ownership of the `ws_stream` and I won't be able to use it multiple times.

I tried using Rc, Arc for the stream but this didn't work. I know it's something with the lifetime, but I don't really understand how they work.

Comment: What libraries are `TcpStream` and `accept_async` from?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).